# primefaces fileupload dialog with file filter extension mode="simple"

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

How to add file filter condition in primefaces 3.5 fileUpload tag,
Its displaying only "All Files" option.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p:fileUpload value="#{demoBean.file2}"
    mode="simple" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/" /> 
</h:form>
```

please advice...

Answer (score 0):

File Upload In Simple  mode

1. allowTypes
2. filesize

and some other attributes are not working In Primefaces.

If you want to use them then change mode from simple to advance or remove attribute of mode because by default mode is advance.